# How to check if I'm holding my iPhone vertically or horizontally using accelerometer?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Im working on a shooting game. There is a bulls eye placed on the middle of screen and a cross hair controlled by accelerometer. I want to check if the user is controlling the device horizontally or vertically. When the user is holding it vertically i don't want the cross hair to scroll down. Cross hair is only to move when i tilt my device vertically or horizontally.
Anyone?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Then:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {

}
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {

}
```

Comment: Checking orientation is not the problem. In my didAccelerate method, what code should i write to make the cross hair move when holding it in vertical position. just like the shooting games.Just like the Guns and Ammo games. Currently the cross hair is moving when I'm holding it horizontally and when i move my device to vertical position the cross hair falls down. I want to make it work when its in vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful , have you tried to use compass api for it ?

Comment: I don't want to user Compass or Gyro or any type of sensor fusion as i want my app to work on both iPhones and iPods.